# Selenium webdriver stops executing test in Firefox

Tags: selenium, firefox

Whenever I run a test script in firefox sometimes it continues to load/keep on loading the page even after 5 mins and at the same time I observed on the left side bottom of the page 'Transferring data from a.rfihub.com...'I had to abort the test run and execute it again. I don't know what this rfihub.com means and why it interferes or delays or stops loading the page. What can I do to prevent this? Need help. Thanks in advance

Comment: Which version of Selenium and Firefox you are using ?

Comment: Firefox 45.0.02. I recently updated Selenium to 2.53

Comment: Okay.. if possible please post web url so that I can try at my end

Comment: It's taking avg 40 sec time to load the whole page. If you manually open link multiple times cache cookies are stored locally so next time if you access it takes less time. But selenium opens a fresh copy of Firefox each time, so no cache,cookies are stored.

Comment: May be your network connection is slow or you need to clean your java cache

Comment: I have a similar problem that since I've updated to firefox 45.0.02 the test stops after 5 minutes. I can reproduce this anytime. The testsuite gets processed, but after 5 minutes the test stop. No log, no error.

Comment: @ShekharSwami - I tried with wired connection. Still seeing this issue.

Comment: @RalfReddin - please let me know if you find a solution.

Comment: I was wrong with my comment. I had a RC test-suite running and that stopped as a testcase filename did not end with .html -- changing that, the test runs ok.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue by enabling DO Not Track option in Firefox. Menu -> Options-> Privacy-> click manage your Do Not Track Settings and uncheck the box. Restart the Firefox. Hope this helps someone facing similar issue in future.